# Actionscript- double click to select a word in a textfield?

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

Can someone tell me how I might enable double clicking to select a word in a input textfield?

Answer (score 0):

It should do this by default if you are using a *TextField* with type *TextFieldType.INPUT*.

Answer (score 0):

If Spencer's idea doesn't work you could do the following:

1. Set doubleClickEnabled=true on the TextField.
2. Add a listener for the DOUBLE_CLICK.
3. When the listener fires, convert the event's (x,y) to a character index by using [TextField.getCharIndexAtPoint](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#getCharIndexAtPoint%28%29).
4. Search before and after that point for either a space or string end/begin and use those two values to set the selection index.